# Is there a way in testcafe to get the load time of specific page elements?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, selector, visibility, testcafe

Suppose I navigate to a page and I want certain page elements to be displayed within a specific time duration. How can I get the time taken for specific page elements to be loaded?

I have tried using visibilityCheck option with selector timeout in the command-line argument.
I also tried exception with a timeout.
Neither of these is working as expected.

```
try {
        await loginPage.signInToPortal()
        await loginPage.login( 'xxxx','yyyy')
        await Selector('div').withText('Something').with({ visibilityCheck: true });
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error("Testcase C111111 failed...")
        throw(e)
    }
```

OR

```
try {
        await loginPage.signInToPortal()
        await loginPage.login( 'xxxx','yyyy')
        const appLabel = Selector('div').withText('Something').with({ visibilityCheck: true });
        await t.expect(appLabel.innerText).contains('Something', { timeout: 5000 });
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error("Testcase C111111 failed...")
        throw(e)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you want to check that the element exists and has some inner text after some period of time. If the time passed, but the element does not exist or does not have some text, you want the test to fail.

Your approach is correct in general, but I think you do not need the `visibilityCheck` option here.

Since I do not know how exactly your project works, I created a sample. Let me show it and explain [how timeouts work](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements.html#selector-timeout) in TestCafe.

The page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

    setTimeout(() => {
        var div = document.createElement('div');

        document.body.appendChild(div);

        setTimeout(() => {
            div.innerHTML = 'test';
        }, 6000);
    }, 6000);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The test code:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `fixture`
    .page `../pages/index.html`;

const selector = Selector('div', { timeout: 4000 });

test(`Recreate invisible element and click`, async t => {
    await t.expect(selector.innerText).eql('test', 'error message', { timeout: 13000 });
});
```

Here, I have a `div` element, which appears only after 6s. During this period, the assertion checks whether the element exists. This code is executed: `Selector('div', { timeout: 4000 });`. Since 4s is less that 6s, the test fails because it cannot find an element during the timeout.

However, if I change the timeout to 7s, `Selector('div', { timeout: 7000});` TestCafe finds the div and starts waiting until the div has correct inner text.

The assertion timeout is 13s now. 13s is greater that 6s (time required for an element to appear) + 6s (time required for an element to have a correct text), so assertion will succeed. However, if I change the assertion timeout from 13s to 11s, it will fail.

See also: [Built-In Wait Mechanisms](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/built-in-wait-mechanisms.html)